# Set file expiration upload PDF

Tags: php, file, php-carbon

I have a website where my customers can upload their PDF instead of mailing this to me. I used a standard copy paste solution for this that looks like this:

```
$newfile->expires_at = $dateInstance->addWeek();
```

I feel that the week until the file expires is way too long. How can i set this to f.i. one day/ 2 days?

Comment: Please can you specify what language and framework are you using? It looks like PHP, but at least tell us the type of `$dateInstance` variable. You should look at documentation for the class of that `$dateInstance` for some method like `addDays` with argument.

Comment: it is php laravel indeed. I know i can use addWeek and addMonth. Could i just use addDay instead? Dateinstance is Carbon

Comment: You use `Carbon` for the `dateInstance`?

Comment: YES { $dateInstance = Carbon::now();}

Answer (score 0):

According to [Carbon documentation](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon#api-addsub) you can use `$dateInstance->addDay()` or `$dateInstance->addDays(2)`.

Comment: Thanks, did not know that, i will try and let you know!

Comment: Does it work? I dont use PHP nor Laravel. I just googled for you.

Comment: This works! Thanks! Sometimes things can be so easy ;)

Comment: I am glad to hear. You can accept my answer by upvoting the answer.